# rsync synchronising a sub-folder while respecting the original folder exclusion rules

Tags: rsync, directory, tar, wildcards

I have a bash script which synchronises a source folder to a destination folder in the presence exclusion rules.

something akin to

```
rsync -l -a -no-g --delete --exclude $PATTERN $SRC $DST
```

I would like to add ability to copy only specific subfolder of $SRC while preserving the original exclude semantics, e.g if `a/b` is subfolder and pattern is `*/*/c` then `$SRC/a/b/c` shall be ignored, but `$SRC/a/b/d`, `$SRC/a/b/e` will be transferred (I hope I got it right) .

I guess one solution is to combine subfoder and $SOURCE and somehow modify or add exclude patterns (something like `rsync ...  --exclude c --exclude a/b/c  $SRC/a/b $DST`)

Or maybe, for a more general solution, it is better to just add --include with the folder content and exclude everything else?
Something like

rsync ... --exclude a/b/c --exclude '*/' --include /a/b/*

rsync ... --exclude $PATTERN --exclude '*/' --include $SUB/* $SRC $DST

looks like addressing specific folders where discussed before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687755/how-to-use-rsync-to-copy-only-specific-subdirectories-same-names-in-several-dir
though not in presence of previous exclude patterns

Assume that folder concatenation problem can be solved, I am more worried of distraction. Also it is unlikely the subfolder itself is totally prohibited by the exclude pattern.

For a moment a best effort solution is fine with me but tell me if I should rather post to stackoverflow or compute science exchange.